# Python library to embed a text editor in an application

Tags: text-editor, python, text-processing

I have an existing application in C++ and Python that can take Python scripts as input to execute some tasks.

I want to let users create or edit these scripts directly in the application. I am looking for a library to perform some classical tasks needed for that, such as:

- Management of copy / paste
- Undo / Redo features
- Maybe syntax highlighting (I already found Pygments for that purpose)
- Auto-completion (I already have some code to generates lists of suggestions based on a keyword / token)
- etc.

Does someone knows Python (or maybe C/C++) libraries or tools that can help me ?

Note: Our application uses our own GUI toolkit instead of existing (PyQt, Tk, etc). This toolkit directly writes shapes in OpenGL, and we already have a "widget" to write and edit multiline texts. We are looking for a tool to provide high level features mentionned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using QSyntaxHighlighter in my Python PyQt application.  I created a class on top of the base textedit field and used QSyntaxHighlighter to create a full color syntax editor for MySQL source code.  Works beautifully and also supports Undo/Redo by default (no extra effort).  I haven't looked into auto-complete yet however.  Just search for examples of QSyntaxHighlighter.  I found an example and was able to modify it to my purposes with little effort.